# How to determine the value of Arg

Tags: complex-numbers

So the Arg is defined by $$\operatorname{Arg}[e^{\frac{-i\pi}{3}}e^{-2+2i}]$$
I've tried to solve it by this way:
$$\cos^{\frac{-\pi}{3}}+\sin^{\frac{-\pi}{3}}(2(\cos 2+i\sin 2))$$ but it looks incorrect. Which theorem I can use to determine values similar to this

Comment: Are you asking what the expression $\text{Arg}\,(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}e^{-2+2i})$ evaluates to?

Comment: @EvanAad so yeah I thought that I can convert e in exp^pi/5, but I'm not sure that is true

Comment: Did you, by any chance, mean $2\pi i$ instead of $2i$?

Comment: @EvanAad no it's -2+2i

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes $\operatorname{Arg}$'s range is $(-\pi,\pi]$.

**If the question is to calculate $\operatorname{Arg}\,(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}e^{-2+2i})$**

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Arg}\,(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}e^{-2+2i}) &= \operatorname{Arg}\,e^{-2+i(2-\frac{\pi}{3})}\\
&= \big(2-\frac{\pi}{3}\big) \mod (-\pi,\pi]\\
&= 2-\frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align*}
$$

* Recall that $\pi \approx 3.14$, so $\pi > 2$, and $2-\frac{\pi}{3} \in (-\pi,\pi]$.

**If the question is to calculate $\operatorname{Arg}\,\big(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}(-2+2i)\big)$**

$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Arg}\,e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}} &= -\frac{1}{3}\pi \mod (-\pi,\pi]\\
&= -\frac{1}{3}\pi\\
\operatorname{Arg}\,(-2+2i) &= \arccos\frac{-2}{|-2+2i|}\\
&= \arccos \frac{-2}{\sqrt{8}}\\
&= \arccos -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
&= \frac{3}{4}\pi\\
\operatorname{Arg}\,(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}(-2+2i)) &= \big(\operatorname{Arg}\,e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}} + \operatorname{Arg}\,(-2+2i)\big) \mod (-\pi,\pi]\\
&= \big(-\frac{1}{3}\pi + \frac{3}{4}\pi\big) \mod (-\pi,\pi]\\
&= \frac{5}{12}\pi \mod (-\pi,\pi]\\
&= \frac{5}{12}\pi
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The argument of a product is the sum of the arguments.

But the question sure sounds wierd, and I would bet on it being a typo for $\arg(e^{-i\pi/3}(-2+2i))$.